# How to extract data from excel having 1:00:00 , 2:00:00 etc format?

Tags: excel

I am having some date(excel sheet), wherein the sheet contains the below structure,

```
Table 1:

A                         B           C
01-Apr-16 1:00:00 AM      13          14.6
01-Apr-16 1:15:00 AM      54          35
05-Mar-16 7:00:00 AM      345         134
05-Mar-16 7:30:00 AM      345         134

Table 2:
```

I need to retrieve table like this,

```
    A                      B           C
01-Apr-16 1:00:00 AM      13          14.6
05-Mar-16 7:00:00 AM      345         134
```

Can anyone give me suggestions of how to approach this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so why was the 2 rows deleted?

Comment: Is your column `A:A` in date or text format?

Comment: @Taosique Its in date format

Comment: what is the criteria for picking out those two lines? - maximum and minimum of something?

Comment: @Gowtham I need to get data whose timestamp is like 1'o clock , 2'o clock etc, not 1.15 am/pm , 2.30 am/pm, 2.45 am/pm etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have dates in `Column A`, enter the below formula in `Column D` (in pic it is col B),

```
=MINUTE(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm"))
```

[image]

You could just then filter the `0` alone and copy paste the required data from all the 3 columns.

Comment: FWIW you do not need to convert it to text just use `=MINUTE(A1)`

Comment: would that still work if the date string is formatted in a different way?

Comment: Yes, If it is a true date, it does not matter how it is formatted.  If it is a string that cannot be converted directly to a date neither formula will work.

Comment: Remember a true date is a number not a string.  The time portion is the decimal portion.  The formatting is a simple visual representation of that number.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the intervening rows then use AGGREGATE to supply the row number to INDEX.

In E2 per the supplied image,

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(1E+99, $A:$A)))/NOT(MINUTE($A$2:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A)))),ROW(1:1)))
```

Fill right and down. Add an IFERROR wrapper if you do not want to show error codes when you run out of matches.

[image]